# Splitting a column into two new columns with same column name

Tags: r

I want to split pairs of values, which are separated by a comma within each column, into two adjacent columns within a new data frame and with the same column name for each of the two new columns.

That is, I want to convert this:

```
A   B   C   D   E 
1,1 0,1 1,1 1,1 1,1 
1,1 1,1 1,1 1,1 1,1
0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1
```

to this:

```
A  A  B  B  C  C  D  D  E  E
1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

If the data frame names can't have exact duplicates, A_1 and A_2... and so on should be ok. Or, having the names in the first row of the dataframe instead of as a header would be ok also.

My actual dataset is ~200 columns by ~13,000 rows, so I need an automated method for splitting columns and assigning names to the second version of the data frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
library(splitstackshape)
(newdf <- cSplit(df, names(df), ","))
#    A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2 D_1 D_2 E_1 E_2
# 1:   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
# 2:   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
# 3:   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

To create duplicate column names, you can then do the following since `data.table` is also loaded with `splitstackshape`

```
setnames(newdf, names(newdf), sub("_.*", "", names(newdf)))
newdf
#    A A B B C C D D E E
# 1: 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 2: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 3: 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

But just so you know, having duplicate column names is a terrible idea.

Comment: +1 of course, but why use `setNames` when you have `setnames` from "data.table" that would do the work without copying?

Comment: Yes cSplit! Beaten to the punch. +1

Comment: Also potentially a better candidate for `cSplit_f`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - mainly because I don't really use data table that much, but I'll go figure it out right now :)

Comment: @jazzurro, here I go, [kicking myself...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26966510/1270695) :-)

Comment: @RichardScriven could you explain to me the purpose of the period in `sub("_.*"`? My colnames are complicated (e.g. X50047.C4Y4MACXX.7.250354917 instead of A), and including the period for some reason causes certain names to split improperly. Underscores only should be ok as they don't appear natively in any colname. Simply removing the period results in the entire line of code not working (no change to the colnames).

Answer (score 4):

Not to kick myself here, but, with recent developments in the "stringi" package, `cSplit` doesn't take the cake for this type of work anymore.

Here's an approach using `Stringi` (though it is specific to *this* problem).

First, create a splitting function:

```
library(stringi)
Stringi <- function(indf) {
  X <- do.call(cbind, lapply(indf, stri_split_fixed, ",", simplify = TRUE))
  `dimnames<-`(`dim<-`(as.numeric(X), dim(X)), 
               list(NULL, paste0(rep(names(indf), each = 2), 1:2)))
}
```

Second, apply it:

```
Stringi(df)
#      A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C2 D1 D2 E1 E2
# [1,]  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [2,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
# [3,]  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

---

On 13000 rows by 200 columns, `cSplit` takes just under 11 seconds for me, and `Stringi` takes less than 2.5 seconds.

---

Obviously, this is something already in consideration for a future version of "splitstackshape" as [this Gist of mine from last month shows](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/3865d516fcc575d7099c) :-) With that version of `cSplit`, the time comes down from from 11 seconds to about 2.7 seconds.

Comment: `stringi` also now has `stri_list2matrix` which is really nice

Comment: @RichardScriven, doesn't work for this. That's what the `simplify` argument calls in `stri_split_fixed` though.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Oh thank you very much for the work! Now I have more to learn. +1 :)